# wpf-DragDrop in a listbox with groupstyle

Tags: wpf, listbox, drag-and-drop, grouping

I am using the control library from http://code.google.com/p/gong-wpf-dragdrop/successfully for my listbox dragging operation.But there is an issue when i drop an item to a listbox with a group style.I have traced that in the DropInfo class the line

```
UiElement item=itemscontrol.GetItemContainerAt(e.GetPosition(itemscontrol));
```

always returns a null. My listbox is bound to a `CollectionViewSource`.

Any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source is now updated and supports drag and drop across listboxes wth group style..

check http://code.google.com/p/gong-wpf-dragdrop/

thanks for your support

Comment: This is really good, but it's on github now